# Sending value through bluetooth

Tags: android

I have set up a bluetooth connection and found the data does not match on the receiver (visually through scope). The issue appears to be the data conversion int to byte.

`buffer[0] = (byte) r_value`

Where `r_value` has a range of 0-255.  All work fin as long as the value is not greater than 127. Anyone have a solution. I have a bluetooth HC-06 slave with a samsung note 10 to send via bluetooth.

Comment: Hi, how are you getting the scope trace - is this on the transmit line of the UART? True that in java a byte is signed but this should not matter it is how it is interpreted at the receiver, 255 => -1 => 0xFF.

Comment: Is this buffer what is written to the output stream of the Bluetooth socket or is there any other processing before hand? Also is it possible to connect your slave to a PC serial port and display the received packet in hex?

Answer (score 0):

`byte` type holds 256 values, within the range of -128...0...127 ( -128 negative number + 127 postive number + 0 ) but `unsigned byte` can hold values 0 to 255.

Edit: unsigned doesn't supported in Java

Comment: It doesn't. All numeric types are "signed" in Java (in quotation marks because `signed` is *not* a Java keyword).

Comment: ah ok, I just wan't sure about that so I mentioned it in paranthesis, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

A `byte` in java is a signed byte; `Byte.MAX_VALUE` = 127 `Byte.MIN_VALUE` = -128.

Comment: Scope is monitoring hc-06 bluetooth module slave Rx pin. I plan to use a Pic18 device to monitor this pin. I have tried several option to convert int to byu

Comment: scope pin on hc-06 Rx pin. The main goal of the project is to send the seekbar value to bluetooth port. sekbar uses int(progress) but the mmOutputStream.write uses byte.